# Generating two series with a certain correlation and a specific condition in R

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements

I want to generate two data series of size 100 in R, one of which is going to be remission time, **tr**, from Exp(mean=1) distribution and the other one is going to be survival time, **t**, from Exp(mean=2.5) distribution. I want them to be negatively correlated (say, the correlation is -0.5). But at the same time I want that R avoids the values of **t[i]** that are less than **tr[i]** for data point **i**, because survival times should be greater than remission times. I have been able to produce some correlation between the two variables (although the correlation is not exactly reproduced) using the following codes:

```
rho <- -0.5
mu <- rep(0,2)
Sigma <- matrix(rho, nrow=2, ncol=2) + diag(2)*(1 - rho)

library(MASS)

rawvars <- mvrnorm(100, mu=mu, Sigma=Sigma)

pvars <- pnorm(rawvars)
    
tr<-rep(0,100)
for(i in 1:100){
tr[i] <- qexp(pvars[,1][i], 1/1)
    }
    
t<-rep(0,100)
for(i in 1:100){
repeat { 
    t[i] <- qexp(pvars[,2][i], 1/2) 
    if (t[i]>tr[i]) break
}
}
    

cor(tr,t)

sum(tr>t) # shows number of invalid cases
```

But how should I efficiently induce the condition so that R only generates values of **t** that are greater than corresponding **tr**?

Moreover, is there a better way (faster way) to do the whole thing in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that `qexp` is the quantile function and will return the same value for the same probability `pvars[,2][i]`. As a result, your code can easily go into an infinite loop when any one of the `pvars[i,]` is such that `t[i]<=tr[i]`. To avoid that, you must regenerate your `rawvars` for each `t[i], tr[i]` pair that fails your condition. In addition, looping over `pvars` is not necessary since `qexp` and operator `>` are all vectorized. The following code does what you want:

```
rho <- -0.5
mu <- rep(0,2)
Sigma <- matrix(rho, nrow=2, ncol=2) + diag(2)*(1 - rho)

library(MASS)
set.seed(1)  ## so that results are repeatable

compute.tr.t <- function(n, paccept) {
  n <- round(n / paccept)
  rawvars <- mvrnorm(n, mu=mu, Sigma=Sigma)
  pvars <- pnorm(rawvars)
  tr <- qexp(pvars[,1], 1/1)
  t <- qexp(pvars[,2], 1/2)
  keep <- which(t > tr)
  return(data.frame(t=t[keep],tr=tr[keep]))
}

n <- 10000  ## generating 10000 instead of 100, this can now be large
paccept <- 1
res <- data.frame()
while (n > 0) {
  new.res <- compute.tr.t(n, paccept)
  res <- rbind(res, new.res)
  paccept <- nrow(new.res) / n
  n <- n - nrow(res)
}
```

Notes:

1. The function `compute.tr.t` borrows a technique from [rejection sampling here](http://www.mas.ncl.ac.uk/~ndjw1/teaching/sim/reject/circ.html). Its input arguments are the requested number of samples that we want and the expected probability of acceptance. With this:

   - It generates `n = n / paccept` exponential variates for both `tr` and `t` as you do to account for the probability of acceptance
   - It only keeps those satisfying the condition `t > tr`.

   What `compute.tr.t` returns may be less than the requested `n` samples. We can then use this information to compute how many more samples we need and what the updated expected probability of acceptance is.
2. We generate the samples satisfying our condition in a `while` loop. In this loop:

   - We call `compute.tr.t` with a requested number of samples to generate and the expected acceptance rate. Initially, these will be set to how many total samples we want and `1`, respectively.
   - The result of `compute.tr.t` are then appended to the result data frame `res`.
   - Updating the probability of accept is simply the ratio of how many samples were returned over how many were requested.
   - Updating the requested number of samples is simply how many more we need from the total number we want.
   - We stop when the next requested number of samples is less than or equal to `0` (i.e., we have enough samples).

   The resulting data frame may contain more than the total number of samples we want.

Running this code, we get:

```
print(cor(res$tr,res$t))
[1] -0.09128498
print(sum(res$tr>res$t)) # shows number of invalid cases
##[1] 0
```

We note that the anti correlation is significantly weaker than expected. This is due to your condition. If we remove this condition by modifying `compute.tr.t` as:

```
compute.tr.t <- function(n, paccept) {
  n <- round(n / paccept)
  rawvars <- mvrnorm(n, mu=mu, Sigma=Sigma)
  pvars <- pnorm(rawvars)
  tr <- qexp(pvars[,1], 1/1)
  t <- qexp(pvars[,2], 1/2)
  return(data.frame(t=t,tr=tr))
}
```

Then we get:

```
print(cor(res$tr,res$t))
##[1] -0.3814602
print(sum(res$tr>res$t)) # shows number of invalid cases
##[1] 3676
```

The correlation is now much more reasonable, but the number of invalid cases is significant.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation and indication of where the problem was. Although the correlation is not exactly reproduced but I can get the desired correlation by tuning rho. Thank you!

Comment: One problem is the resulting data sometimes contain less data than required number of sample.

Comment: @BlainWaan: are you saying that the while loop finishes before n samples that fit your condition are generated?

Comment: Yes, but now I have been able to resolve this. Thank you for your kind help!

Comment: @BlainWaan: just to let you know, there is a low-probability edge case where `n <- round(n / paccept)` returns `1`. In this case, the above code will fail because `rawvars` and `pvars` will be a vector of two elements and not a matrix with 2 columns. To prevent this from ever happening, simply replace that line of code with `n <- max(round(n / paccept), 2)` so that at least two samples is generated.

Comment: I understand that because of the condition imposed (t>tr) the locations of the generated data series shift. But is there a way to keep the mean of tr as roughly 1 and the mean of t near 2?

Comment: @BlainWaan: I don't know of a way. Note that the samples you keep no longer fit an exponential distribution. I suggest that you ask the question on [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com) where there are many more statisticians who may be able to answer your question or suggest a better method to generate what you want.