# Simulating two conditional variable with specified means and a correlation using R

Tags: r, loops, conditional-statements, simulation

This question arose from [one of my previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38911350/generating-two-series-with-a-certain-correlation-and-a-specific-condition-in-r) where the problem of generating two correlated series was resolved with some limitations. We were trying to produce two correlated series that followed exponential distributions with certain parameters. For example, a variable **tr** with mean **1** and another variable **t** with mean **2** with a correlation of **-0.5** were required satisfying the condition that **t>tr**). The following codes were tried in `R`.

```
rho   <- -0.5
mu    <- rep(0,2)
Sigma <- matrix(rho, nrow=2, ncol=2) + diag(2)*(1 - rho)

library(MASS)

compute.tr.t <- function(req.n, paccept) {
  req.n      <- round(req.n / paccept)
  rawvars    <- mvrnorm(req.n, mu=mu, Sigma=Sigma)
  pvars      <- pnorm(rawvars)
  tr         <- qexp(pvars[,1], 1/1)
  t          <- qexp(pvars[,2], 1/2)
  keep       <- which(t > tr)
  return(data.frame(t=t[keep],tr=tr[keep]))
}

req.n   <- n
paccept <- 1
res     <- data.frame()

while (req.n > 0) {
  new.res <- compute.tr.t(req.n, paccept)
  res     <- rbind(res, new.res)
  req.n   <- n - nrow(res)
  paccept <- nrow(new.res) / n# updated paccept according to last step
}
```

The problem that occurred due to pruning data that do not satisfy the condition **t>tr**:

1. The means were not preserved.
2. The correlation was not preserved.

See the output below. It is evident that because of imposing such a condition the locations shift.

```
mean(res$tr)
 [1] 0.4660927
 mean(res$t)
 [1] 2.859441
 print(cor(res$tr,res$t))
 [1] -0.237159
```

**My question:** is there a way to achieve two correlated and conditional variables (such that **t>tr**) keeping the series means near to that of the specified means? We may go along with the reduced correlation, but is it possible to at least preserve the means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated answer** *every element* of t strictly greater than tr:

```
n     <- 100
rho   <- 0.5
mu    <- rep(0,2)
Sigma <- matrix(rho, nrow=2, ncol=2) + diag(2)*(1 - rho)

library(MASS)

compute.tr.t <- function(req.n, paccept) {
  req.n      <- round(req.n / paccept)
  rawvars    <- mvrnorm(req.n, mu=mu, Sigma=Sigma)
  pvars      <- pnorm(rawvars)
  tr         <- qexp(pvars[,1], 1/1)
  t          <- qexp(pvars[,2], 1/2)
  tr         <- tr[(tr-mean(tr))^2  <.25 ] # can play with this value
  t          <- t[(t-mean(t))^2  <.25 ]
  m          <- min(length(t), length(tr))
  t          <- t[1:m]
  tr         <- tr[1:m]
  return(data.frame(t=t,tr=tr))
}

req.n   <- n
paccept <- 1
res     <- data.frame()

while (req.n > 0) {
  new.res <- compute.tr.t(req.n, paccept)
  res     <- rbind(res, new.res)
  req.n   <- n - nrow(res)
  paccept <- nrow(new.res) / n
}

mean(res$t)
```

> [1] 1.972218

```
mean(res$tr)
```

> [1] 0.590776

```
table(res$t > res$tr) # should be all true, rarely you'll get 1 trivial false that you can kick out
```

> ```
>  TRUE 
>  132
> ```

```
cor(res$t,res$tr) # suffered a little but not too bad, can probably improve
```

> [1] .2527064

**Original answer** mean(t) > mean(tr) but not every element:

```
n     <- 100
rho   <- 0.5
mu    <- rep(0,2)
Sigma <- matrix(rho, nrow=2, ncol=2) + diag(2)*(1 - rho)

library(MASS)

compute.tr.t <- function(req.n, paccept) {
  req.n      <- round(req.n / paccept)
  rawvars    <- mvrnorm(req.n, mu=mu, Sigma=Sigma)
  pvars      <- pnorm(rawvars)
  tr         <- qexp(pvars[,1], 1/1)
  t          <- qexp(pvars[,2], 1/2)
  keep       <- which(t > tr)
  return(data.frame(t=t,tr=tr))
}

req.n   <- n
paccept <- 1
res     <- data.frame()

while (req.n > 0) {
  new.res <- compute.tr.t(req.n, paccept)
  res     <- rbind(res, new.res)
  req.n   <- n - nrow(res)
  paccept <- nrow(new.res) / n# updated paccept according to last step
}

mean(res$tr)
```

> [1] 0.9399213

```
mean(res$t)
```

> [1] 1.795431

```
print(cor(res$tr,res$t))
```

> [1] 0.5075668

Since there's some randomness in this for good measure I ran it a 2nd time and got the following result:

```
mean(res$tr)
```

> [1] 1.001255

```
mean(res$t)
```

> [1] 1.922343

```
print(cor(res$tr,res$t))
```

> [1] 0.6648311

After you run it once if you don't quite like the results a simple hack to meet any desired level of precision is:

```
while(
  (cor(res$tr,res$t) > .55 | cor(res$tr,res$t) < .45)
){
  n     <- 100
  rho   <- 0.5
  mu    <- rep(0,2)
  Sigma <- matrix(rho, nrow=2, ncol=2) + diag(2)*(1 - rho)

  library(MASS)

  compute.tr.t <- function(req.n, paccept) {
    req.n      <- round(req.n / paccept)
    rawvars    <- mvrnorm(req.n, mu=mu, Sigma=Sigma)
    pvars      <- pnorm(rawvars)
    tr         <- qexp(pvars[,1], 1/1)
    t          <- qexp(pvars[,2], 1/2)
    keep       <- which(t > tr)
    return(data.frame(t=t,tr=tr))
  }

  req.n   <- n
  paccept <- 1
  res     <- data.frame()

  while (req.n > 0) {
    new.res <- compute.tr.t(req.n, paccept)
    res     <- rbind(res, new.res)
    req.n   <- n - nrow(res)
    paccept <- nrow(new.res) / n# updated paccept according to last step
  }
}
```

Comment: Although I didn't downvote your answer, but this answer is not what I desired. You skip the condition that t>tr. If you skip this condition then the correlation as well as the means will be preserved. But how can I preserve the means and correlations when the condition that t>tr is met?

Comment: @BlainWaan What do you mean that I skip t > tr? I ensured that the average value of t is approx. 2 and the average value of tr is 1. That's why t is approximately twice tr in all of the results. 1.79 > .93. 1.922343 > 1.001255. Do you mean that *every single element* of t has to be greater than tr? If so, that's a bit different but we can do it. I am late for work so I have to go but I can show you after I'm at work.

Comment: Yes, I meant that every single element of t has to be greater than tr. Sorry for not being clear enough to you.

Comment: @BlainWaan OK I updated it. Basically just trim based on standard deviation / squared variance.

Comment: Thank you. But could you please explain the trick of trimming based on SD?

Comment: @BlainWaan Sure, the idea is just that as long as you exclude data based on how much it varies from the mean then the mean should remain constant. Since the means are different for `t` and `tr` as the data is filtered to only data points close to the means the ranges no longer overlap.